# Как "узнать" определённый USB-накопитель с помощью python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Код должен узнавать определённую флешку, подключённую к ПК на Windows. Пробовал делать это посредством создания ключ-файла на накопителе, а код каждые несколько секунд проверяет наличие этого файла. Понятное дело, что способ этот костыльный и работает неидеально. Есть ли более надёжный способ?

Comment: а какая OS вам нужна?

Comment: @inzem77, извините, как-то из головы вылетело уточнить это. Мне нужно чтобы это работало на Windows

Comment: Попробуйте https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58857920/how-to-get-connected-usb-device-list-from-windows-by-using-python-or-cmd

Comment: @inzem77, да, спасибо. Думаю, что если кое-что подправить, то можно использовать данный метод в моём случае

Answer (score 0):

*Ай, блин. Это для линукса. Ну пусть останется.*

---

У флешек есть свое "имя" вида XXXX-XXXX. Его можно получить например так:

```
$ df -h
```

В колонке "Mounted on" будет что-то вроде `/media/username/ABCD-4321`. Ну и потом проверять наличе такого накопителя в выводе команды.

Еще можно использовать

```
$ lsblk
```